# Spring MVC Test with RequestPostProcessor vs. Annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jhipster, spring-mvc-test, spring-security-test

I have an application I've created with JHipster. I generated a Blog entity, then modified the `BlogResource` class so its `getAll()` method only returns the blog for the current user.

```
/**
 * GET  /blogs -> get all the blogs.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/blogs",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<Blog> getAll() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Blogs");
    return blogRepository.findAllForCurrentUser();
}
```

`BlogRepository` has the following for its `findAllForCurrentUser()` method.

```
@Query("select blog from Blog blog where blog.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
List<Blog> findAllForCurrentUser();
```

To test this, I was able to use Spring Security's `RequestPostProcessor`:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllBlogs() throws Exception {
    restBlogMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();

    // Initialize the database
    blog.setUser(userRepository.findOneByLogin("user").get());
    blogRepository.saveAndFlush(blog);

    // Get all the blogs
    restBlogMockMvc.perform(get("/api/blogs").with(user("user")))
        //.andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(blog.getId().intValue())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].name").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NAME.toString())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].handle").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_HANDLE.toString())));
}
```

I'm curious to know why using annotations like `@WithMockUser` and `@WithUserDetails` won't work for this. If I change it to use annotations, I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] org.jhipster.app.security.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```