# Jhipster - JpaRepository "principal.username" @Query - org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException

Tags: java, testing, spring-security, jhipster, spelevaluationexception

I have an error while I am testing my rest controller on a specific method. I am using the `@Query` annotation to do my database query. And it's using the "principal.username" to do it. I don't have the all picture on how principal.username is fetched and used in my application. I am currently looking at the spring-security documentation about it. But my problem is in the test part, when I execute the test below, I have an error "Faillure" because of the `@Query`.

The repository:

```
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting,Long> {

  @Query("select m from Meeting m where m.visibility = 'PUBLIC' OR m.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
  List<Meeting> findOpenAndUserMeetings();

}
```

A Rest Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/meetings", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Meeting>> getAll()
{
    List<Meeting> meetings = MeetingRepository.findOpenAndUserMeetings();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Meeting>>(meetings, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

A test:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllMeetings() throws Exception {
    // Initialize the database
    MeetingRepository.saveAndFlush(Meeting);

    // Get all the Meetinges
    restMeetingMockMvc.perform(get("/api/meetings"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

And this error:

```
getAllMeetings(com.ent.web.rest.MeetingResourceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.07 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 10): Property or field 'username' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:372)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.evaluateExpression(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:131)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.potentiallyBindExpressionParameters(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:89)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:69)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateCountQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:109)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createCountQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:173)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.findOpenAndUserMeetings(Unknown Source)
        at com.ent.web.rest.MeetingResource.getAll(MeetingResource.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:144)
        at com.ent.web.rest.MeetingResourceTest.getAllMeetings(MeetingResourceTest.java:151)
```

**Edit**

How to be able to use this "?#{principal.username}" in the test? After investigating, I found that here: [Spring Security 4.0: WebSocket, Spring Data and Test Support](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/04/spring-security-4)

**Spring Data Integration**
It is now possible to access the current user within Spring Data queries using SpEL. To enable this feature with Java Configuration, you can define a @Bean.

```
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension(){
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

Then you can refer to Spring Security's principal in your queries. For example:

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog,Long> {
    @Query("select blog from Blog blog where blog.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    List<Blog> findAllForCurrentUser();
}
```

Is it a context problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my project, I have a repository that uses `#{principal.username}` in one of its queries. Here's what it looks like:

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long> {

    @Query("select blog from Blog blog where blog.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    List<Blog> findAllForCurrentUser();
}
```

My `BlogResource` controller calls this as follows:

```
 @Timed
 public List<Blog> getAll() {
     log.debug("REST request to get all Blogs for current user");
     return blogRepository.findAllForCurrentUser();
 }
```

To test this, I upgraded to Spring Security 4.0.1 and added a dependency on spring-security-test:

```
<spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In `BlogResourceTest`, I added dependencies on `WebApplicationContext` and `UserRepository`:

```
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext context;

@Inject
UserRepository userRepository;
```

Then I modified the `getAllBlogs()` test to use Spring Security's "with(user(username))" functionality.

```
 @Test
 @Transactional
 public void getAllBlogs() throws Exception {
    restBlogMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();

     // Initialize the database
     blog.setUser(userRepository.findOneByLogin("user").get());
     blogRepository.saveAndFlush(blog);

     // Get all the blogs
    restBlogMockMvc.perform(get("/api/blogs").with(user("user")))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(blog.getId().intValue())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].name").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NAME.toString())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].handle").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_HANDLE.toString())));
 }
```

I don't know why Spring Security's test annotations (@WithMockUser and @WithUserDetails) don't work. I asked a question about this a week ago:

[Spring MVC Test with RequestPostProcessor vs. Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330975/spring-mvc-test-with-requestpostprocessor-vs-annotations)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working, hope there will be a way with "@WithMockUser" and "@WithUserDetails".

Comment: I know this is 2017, but does this still persist in jhipster 5.8.2?

Comment: I've got a solution to this problem easily. I do not have points to put in the answers.
public static void createUserInContextWithAuthoritiesWithSpringUserDetail(String principal, String credentials, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        User springUserDetail = new User(principal, credentials, authorities);
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(springUserDetail, credentials, authorities));
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);